# psycopg2 doesn't save data in to postgres database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

So I am web scraping from a news site for certain articles. And I am using psycopg2 to connect to postgres database and save data from this article.

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    query = """INSERT INTO
    articles (title, article_body, author, author_title, source_date, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"""
    cur.execute(query, (articleTitle, parsedText, articleAuthor, articleAuthorTitle, articlePostDate, now, now))
    cur.execute('SELECT author FROM articles')
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print ('')
    print (rows)
    print ('')
```

The thing is that when second query is executed, it returns the data from the articles table, but when I make a query through terminal `psql` it shows that articles table is empty.

Comment: You should commit after you execute the insert query. Add this line `conn.commit()` after the line `cur.execute(query, (articleTitle,...`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Completely forgot about commiting

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I add it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    query = """INSERT INTO
    articles (title, article_body, author, author_title, source_date, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"""
    cur.execute(query, (articleTitle, parsedText, articleAuthor, articleAuthorTitle, articlePostDate, now, now))
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute('SELECT author FROM articles')
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print ('')
    print (rows)
    print ('')
```